# Jquery/ Javascript toggle function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, toggle

I have a short code of Javascript which toggles four different links. When clicking one of the links a new box with text appears or disappears. Everything worked fine for the past weeks until 15 minutes ago (I apparently did something wrong).

When the page opens, all the new boxes are shown, when clicking one of the links all the boxes are closed.

I want that all the links (with new boxes) are closed when someone opens the page for the first time.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Many thanks in advance!

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
  $('.newboxes').each(function(index) {
       if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
            $(this).toggle(200);
       }
       else {
            $(this).hide(600);
       }
  });
  }
```

Comment: share a fiddle or your html too

Comment: use display:none; for all boxes

Comment: Hehe I accidently removed display:none

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for document ready function, this will hide the classes or ID's that you want to hide so:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {   
 here you want to hide all the boxes with the links e.g.:
   $('#idName').hide();
   $('#idName2').hide();
});
```

And when some button is clicked show those ID's e.g.

```
$( "#someID" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Do Something" );
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I assume you defined the function call inline in HTML, like so:

```
<a href="javascript:showonlyone('i1');">Open 1</a>
<a href="javascript:showonlyone('i2');">Open 2</a>
<a href="javascript:showonlyone('i3');">Open 3</a>
<a href="javascript:showonlyone('i4');">Open 4</a>
```

and you defined your `<script>` in the `<head>`

if yes, this should work: http://jsfiddle.net/yc2J7/

EDIT

I have add'd `<body onload="showonlyone()">` to the HTML to make it working with your example.